# Prove that $5 n \log_{2}(n) + 8 n -200 = \mathcal{O}(n \log_{2}(n))$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Ive been working on this problem for quite sometime now but cant seem to figure it out

This is what ive done so far:

$$5nlog_2(n)+8n-200 \le cnlog_2(n)$$
$$5+\frac{8}{log_2(n)}-\frac{200}{nlog_2(n)} \le c$$

I found LHS is $>0$ only for $n>=9$

Substituting $n=9$ :
$$5+\frac{8}{log_2(9)}-\frac{200}{9log_2(9)} \le c$$
$$c \ge 5+\frac{8}{log_2(9)}-\frac{200}{9log_2(9)}$$
$$c \ge 0.513388419$$

As $c$ is an integer, $c \ge 1$

So for $n\ge 9$, $5nlog_2(n)+8n-200 \le nlog_2(n)$

When i plot these graphs, its very clear that the inequality does not hold...

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: As $n$ gets larger, your $c$ needs to be well over $5$ and not $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest more easy way($n \geqslant 2$):
$$5n \log_2(n)+8n-200 \leqslant 8n \log_2(n) + 8n \log_2(n) = 16n \log_2(n)$$

Comment: Basically we assume another simpler function that is always greater than the original function and then use that instead of f(n) because in the limit its not going to matter?

Comment: @Mohammad Areeb Siddiqui. Basically I can agree with your sentence, but prefer not to use limit, if it's possible, but rather simple inequalities. Though, sometimes, limits gives good result.

Comment: Yeap understood! limit isn't really the right thing to say here. Thank you so much for the clarification!